# Do we have to use SPA with RESTful API backend?

Tags: django, web

I am curious about the question stated in the title.

I understand the pros/cons of SPA + RESTful stack vs Dynamic Web Pages.

**But is it reasonable to use other front-end architectures to communicate with RESTful API backend?**

Using Django as an example, can we create TWO Django applications, one serves as our front-end, one serves as our RESTful API Backend (via Django Rest Framework). When a user requests a page, the front-end application will makes calls to the back-end API to fetch and display the data, then sends back the requested page.

Appreciate your feedback/insights!

Comment: What's SPA? I haven't heard of that before.

Comment: Could mean single page application.

Comment: I am planning to split my DRF backend into two separate DRF projects. One will be a database to have an overview of products, their suppliers, prices, stock, etc. The other will be a backend for a webshop, the webshop backend will get some of its data from the "product" backend. I have these two now in one backend, but now I realize that I want them separated, since the two backend have their own distinct function/responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of any Restful service is to have single backend to be able to communicate with multiple platforms like websites, Mobile app, IOT etc.
The intentions of SPA were clearly not to hit the server for every html page rather serve a single html page and change content based on the data or conditions using JavaScript. If you like to serve your SPA through django its possible to put the completely built index.html with all resources in static directory and serve through django which will internally use restapi.Then you Only need to write a single view to serve index.html file.

Comment: You raised a point that I am interested too. When you said using django to serve SPA built index.html, is it simply just creating a view that returns that index.html?

Comment: Yes thats true.just a single view to return index.html or just serve through url

Comment: You may need to put all js and css files in static directory and chenge their path in index.html

Comment: Can't all those SPAs (websties, mobile apps etc·) communicate with a database server which acts a backend ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is possible, whether it is a good idea completely depends on your needs. When using an API it is is quite possible that the API that you are calling is built with Django so in practice i'm sure there are a lot of Django backends communicating with each other. You can call your django-rest backend from wherever you want.

Comment: But can you think of what are the needs to use a django as a frontend only project?

Comment: You would just have everything you have for a regular django app but no model. Instead of the model you would send requests to your other backend.